# Calculate negative vertical offset from paragraph so image floats just above anchor?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on an MS Word function to simplify floating image layout. 
 
Consider the case where there's a normal, single column, page of text and the image floats on the right. When we want the image just below the paragraph, that's 'easy' (error handling removed):

```
Dim myShape As Shape
Set myShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
With myShape
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph
    .Top = 0
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
    .Left = wdShapeRight
End With
```

That's usually all that's needed. But when the anchor is near the end of a page and that would make the image go below the bottom of the page, that can cause an ugly blank space at the bottom of the page:

[image: Image just below para causes large gap at end of page]

I want to avoid moving the anchor. Instead, it's often enough to put the image just above the anchor instead of just below it. But I cannot work out how to do that in code. In this example, the image height is 2". But if I set the 'relative vertical position' to -2", the image floats about half an inch too high:

[image: Relative vertical position = -height. Half inch too high.]

To what value should I set the relative vertical position for the image to float just above the anchor?

P.s. the rules are in http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111mitt-float.pdf and the first step is images in textboxes https://www.securedevelopment.org/2019/08/18/three-powerful-techniques-to-position-images-and-tables-in-word/ . If there's interest I'll open source the functions and examples.

Comment: You haven't really explained what you're trying to accomplish. You first example is about moving the image below the text, which you could do easily by making the image inline instead of floating. But then the second section seems to be about merely moving the image further down the page. Perhaps you could tell us what "simplify floating image layout" means to you.

Comment: @yokki Thanks, yes, that explains what's happening. So probably the only way is to fudge it. I'll try 'inching' the image up a line at a time until the bottom is above the anchor.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Good point! My mission in this is to position a right floating image so that it moves with the text _without_ sometimes leaving big gaps at the bottom of the page. This was one possible solution, but I've not got it to work. Actually I've found another solution: to use vertical positioning _centered_ relative to _line_, which seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks, @yokki. This is what I've come up with. It seems fast enough. It assumes that the para spacing is consistent and that the shape is not near the top of the page. **Note**: this is not a complete answer, as the image doesn't move with the paragraph afterwards.

```
Dim myShape As Shape
Set myShape = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
With myShape
    .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
    .Left = wdShapeRight
    Set AnchorParagraph = .Anchor.Paragraphs(1)
    ParaSpacing = AnchorParagraph.SpaceAfter
    Set AnchorParagraph = .Anchor.Paragraphs(1)
    ParaSpacing = AnchorParagraph.SpaceAfter
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
    .Top = AnchorParagraph.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) - .Height - ParaSpacing
    Do Until .Top + .Height + 1 + ParaSpacing > AnchorParagraph.Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
        .IncrementTop (1)
    Loop
End With
```

To get proper floating, I've found another solution: to use vertical positioning centered relative to line.