# Word VBA function to find location on page of floating image?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Given a floating image with square wrapping, positioned vertically relative to a paragraph:

```
imageShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph
```

How do you get its actual vertical position (in points) on the page?

I've tried:

1. Selecting it and using `Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)`, which gives the anchor location, not the image one.
2. Converting it to `wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage` and reading the `.Top` location, which works, but then converting it back to `wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph` again moves the image.

The motivation for this question is at [Calculate negative vertical offset from paragraph so image floats just above anchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118438/calculate-negative-vertical-offset-from-paragraph-so-image-floats-just-above-anc/59138735#59138735)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Dim RelPos As Long
With imageShape
  RelPos = .RelativeVerticalPosition
  .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
  MsgBox .Top
  .RelativeVerticalPosition = RelPos
End With
```

This works for me without changing the image position.

If you want to calculate the position from the top of the page, change wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin to wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage

Comment: Genius @macropod! Word doesn't have the same bug converting between Relative to Margin and Relative to Paragraph, and we can calculate the actual position by adding the top margin.

Comment: @CharlesW Well, if you want to calculate the position from the top of the page, change wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin to wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage...

Comment: Oops! @macropod For some reason it doesn't work in situ (I didn't do my testing properly - shame on me!). What I see when I use your code on an image with RelativeVerticalPosition=....Paragraph and negative .Top is that the image jumps up or down when I do .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin, and the image jumps back when the image is restored.